# Retrieving more-generic bindings from Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

Imagine I have the following types

```
public interface IFoo{}
public class Foo1 : IFoo{}
public class Foo2 : IFoo{}
```

Which are bound to Ninject as

```
Bind<Foo1>().ToSelf();
Bind<Foo2>().ToSelf();
```

Is there a way I can get all instances of IFoo from a kernel? Calling `kernel.GetAll<IFoo>()` returns an empty result.  I am not in a position to bind IFoo to Foo etc

**Edit**
I would be happy to be able to get all bindings, and manually inspect them via reflection, but can't see anything obvious

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Please read about multi injection in ninject

[Multi injection](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Multi-injection)

In your case might be:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>();
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>();
Bind<Foo1>().ToSelf();
Bind<Foo2>().ToSelf();
```

If you want get list of all bindings you can try use this extension method:

```
    public static Type[] GetBindings(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        return ((Multimap<Type, IBinding>)typeof(KernelBase)
            .GetField("bindings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(kernel)).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
    }
```

[source](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/104)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to Bind<IFoo>.To<Foo>(); this is what makes the situation problematic.  Specifically, I have a load of bindings pre-built, which I cannot reasonable modify in-situ, and I need to be able extract into from the bindings.

Comment: Yes, but that too requires a Type as a parameter (even though the code in the issue does not)

Comment: Doh!  That isn't an official method!  I'll just copy the source.  Thanks!

Comment: Good ;) No problem :)